# Converting [[a]] -> Set (Set a) in haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I am trying to convert a list of lists into a set of sets in haskell.

```
setOfSet :: [[a]] -> Set (Set a)
```

I have defined my set as such

```
data Set a = Leaf | Node (Set a) a (Set a)
```

So essentially my Set (Set a) would be a binary tree in which each node is binary tree (Which is the set). My lists are already ordered so i've been able to to this:

```
SetOfSet x:xs = Node Leaf (fromList x) (setOfSet xs)
```

But i'm now wondering if theres a more effective way

Comment: Welcome to SO! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please pose an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: `SetOfSet x:xs = Node Leaf (fromList x) (setOfSet xs)` can't compile, I suppose what you mean is `setOfSet (x:xs) = Node Leaf (fromList x) (setOfSet xs)`? And, that is indeed not very effective; in particular the outer tree is degenerate. But if you have already implemented `fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a` you should have ideas how to improve it. Write down your thoughts and then we can take the question from there.

Comment: Yes so I have an implementation of ```fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a``` however in my setOfSets function I used a different one that doesn’t use Ord. if I’m correct in my understanding the fromList with ord will not work unless there is Ord in setOfSets

Comment: so the fromList function i used in setOfSets is: ```orderedFromList :: [a] -> Set a``` which is basically defined the same as setOfSet meaning that its also degenerate.

Comment: My input list into orderedFromList is also already ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a second look at your type: `[a] -> Set a`. If you have a list of `a`s, you can get a set of `a`s.

So consider what happens if you give this function to `map`:

```
map orderedFromList :: [[a]] -> [Set a]
```

and then what happens if you apply `orderedFromList` to a list of sets:

```
orderedFromList . map orderedFromList :: [[a]] -> Set (Set a)
```

So

```
setOfSets :: [[a]] -> Set (Set a)
setOfSets = orderedFromList . map orderedFromList
```

Assuming `orderedFromList` makes any effort to build a balanced tree, this gives you a better result than your function, which essentially just builds a linked list of sets.

Comment: Thank you, I have built my ```orderedFromList``` function to build balanced trees and this helps simplify my solution alot.